# Integral of a weighted function

Tags: integration, computational-mathematics, maple

I am trying to compute the following integral. Unfortunately, I do not have Maple(or any other program handy). I got stuck calculating it by hand:
$$
\left(\int_0^tw(s)+t^p\int_t^{\infty}s^{-p}w(s) ds\right)^{1/p}, \quad p\geq1
$$
where
$$
w(x)=\frac{1}{x(1-\ln x)^2}, \quad  \textit{if} \quad  0<x<1
$$
and
$$
w(x)=\frac{x^{p-1}}{(1+\ln x)^2}, \quad \textit{if} \quad x\geq 1
$$

Comment: Any conditions on $p$ ?

Comment: $p\geq1$, thank you

Comment: any condition on $t$?

Comment: $t$ is just in parameter in the integral. technically, $0\leq t< \infty$

Comment: For this integral $\int_t^{\infty}s^{-p}w(s) ds$ when $0<x<1$ it does not look like it is the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\int \frac1{x\left(1 - \ln x\right)^2}\mathrm d x = \frac1{1 - \ln x} + C$$

Comment: Yes, that one I have been able to compute. How about integral from t to infinity?

Comment: It is the same function. No?

Comment: For this integral $\int_t^{\infty}s^{-p}w(s) ds$ when $0<x<1$ it does not look like it is the same function.

Comment: The problem is that the integral is divergent. The problem is when $\ln(x) = 1$ where $x=e$

Comment: But $0<x<1$-so $x\neq 1$

Comment: Now you can use the same idea

Comment: The hint would not work for the second integral. Try evaluating it for 0<x<1.